# Can't parse byte in FxFF format

Tags: c#

I need to parse a byte in this format `Byte b = Byte.Parse("0x20");` but that code does not work even though `Byte b=0x20` works fine. My question is how do I parse a byte in this format `0x06` or any kind of string in that format `FxFF`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll either need to [`SubString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1) before you pass to [`Byte.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte.parse?view=netcore-3.1) with `NumberStyles.HexNumber` (or similar) or use [`Convert.ToByte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobyte?view=netcore-3.1#System_Convert_ToByte_System_String_System_Int32_) with the appropriate *base*:

> Converts the string representation of a number in a specified base to
> an equivalent 8-bit unsigned integer.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> If fromBase is 16, you can prefix the number specified by the value parameter with `0x` or `0X`.

```
var hex = "0x20";
var byte = Byte.Parse(hex.SubString(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
var byte = Convert.ToByte(hex, 16);
```

You **can't** use `byte.Parse` with any `NumberStyles` on a string prefixed `0x` or `0X`, it just can't deal with them.

**HexNumber**

> Indicates that the **AllowLeadingWhite**, **AllowTrailingWhite**, and
> **AllowHexSpecifier** styles are used. This is a composite number style.

**AllowHexSpecifier**

> Indicates that the numeric string represents a hexadecimal value.
> Valid hexadecimal values include the numeric digits 0-9 and the
> hexadecimal digits A-F and a-f. **Strings that are parsed using this
> style cannot be prefixed with "0x" or "&h"**.

Answer (score 1):

The style parameter defines the style elements (such as white space or the positive sign) that are allowed in the s parameter for the parse operation to succeed. It must be a combination of bit flags from the NumberStyles enumeration. Depending on the value of style, the s parameter may include the following elements:

```
[ws][$][sign]digits[.fractional_digits][e[sign]digits][ws]
```

Or, if the style parameter includes AllowHexSpecifier:

```
[ws]hexdigits[ws]
```

hexdigits   A sequence of hexadecimal digits from 0 through f, or 0 through F.

from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte.parse?view=netcore-3.1